# Close window menu when clicking on root

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I'm having trouble figuring out how to close a python tkinter window menu when clicking on the root of the menu, ie."File".

I was hoping there was just a command option available when instantiating the menu but it appears as though that is not the case. Also I know that there is an unpost method I can use to get rid of the menu but I don't know how I would trigger it on root menu click.

Edit:

Since Bryan said that my menus should be acting the same as any other menus in my os I decided to put together an example of how I'm doing menus. Maybe I am doing something wrong here but on ubuntu in every other program if I click on the root of the menu it will close it again. In this program it does not close when clicking on the root, only when clicking elsewhere on the screen does the menu close.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("App Here")
        self.window_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.window_menu, tearoff=0)
        self.build_window_menu()
        self.config(menu=self.window_menu)

    def build_window_menu(self):
        self.window_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)

        self.filemenu.add_command(label='alert', command=self._handle_menualert)

    def _handle_menualert(self):
        tk.messagebox.showwarning(
            "Menu Stuff",
            "I am menu alert!"
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `destroy()` is a method that exists for every tkinter widgets; you can call it on a `Menu` object

Comment: Which OS are you running on? Clicking on the root menu option on Windows does close child menu.

Comment: On Mac it closes as well.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Is there a way to call destroy when clicking on the root though?

Comment: @scotty3785 I am on Ubuntu, that very well could be my issue. I could deal with ignoring it for now if its just doing this on Linux. I'll give it a try on Windows and Mac.

Comment: menubar behavior is platform-specific. Your menubar should be behaving how all other menubars on your platform behave.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried some other programs out on Ubuntu and every other program when I click on the root of the menu it closes again. I added an example of how I am doing menus, it works as expected on osx, but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: @SeanO Confirm, on debian, does not close. But in firefox it closes. `bind(...` will trigger with `self.window_menu.bind(...`, but not with `self.filemenu.bind(...`. `unpost` does not close. I assume the *click* event will always do `post(...` again.